# DFA Construction

Tags: automation, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

I am still getting the hang of Finite Automata, and I am currently stuck on this example (This is from an ungraded study guide for all who are wondering). I am confused on how to implement a DFA for this problem... I guess my main issue is how to keep count of how many characters have been entered and if all other constraints were reached...

```
You must construct passwords from the following alphabet
{a,b,c,A,B,C,0,1,2} with the these additional constraints:

valid passwords must be at least 5 characters long
they must contain at least one lower-case letter
they must contain at least one upper-case letter
and they must contain at least one digit.

Design a DFA accepting only valid passwords.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 conditions to satisfy simultaneously,

Let us call the conditions **P**, **Q**, **R**, and **S**

- **P**: The accepted string has to be *at least* 5 characters long
- **Q**: The accepted string must contain *at least* one lower-case letter
- **R**: The accepted string must contain *at least* one upper-case letter
- **S**: The accepted string and they must contain *at least* one digit.

Irrespective of the other conditions, each condition can be either true or false.

If we denote **true** with 1 and **false** with 0, we get 16
*distinct* different possibilities that we can visualize using a truth
table (grouped for legibility):

```
P | Q | R | S
---------------

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1

0   1   0   0
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   0
0   1   1   1

1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0
1   0   1   1

1   1   0   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1
```

Let us represent the first row with `q[0, 0, 0, 0]`, the second `q[0,
0, 0, 1]` and so on. We won't actually use all the states, specifically

```
1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1
1   0   1   0
1   0   1   1
1   1   0   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0
```

will remain un-used. We will however require one additional state that
do not have a semantic equivalent in the truth table. We will call
this state `Foo`. More on that later.

Now we have to specify the transitions for each
state, as well as identify our initial state.

For each state the transition for each input character has to be described.
Let us adopt the notation that

```
q[0, 0, 0, 0] ---ABC--> q[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

to mean that when we are in the state `q[0, 0, 0, 0]` and we read *any* of the
characters `A`, `B`, or `C` we perform the above state transition.

Now, I will only show a portion of the final DFA as we can compose the
rest of the solution using it as a template.

`q[0, 0, 0, 0]` is our initial state and for the input "ABC" we get

```
q[0, 0, 0, 0] ---ABC--> q[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

We've now read a upper-case letter. From here there are three possibilities,
we read another upper-case letter and stay in the same state:

```
q[0, 0, 1, 0] ---ABC--> q[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

or we read either a set of digits, or a set of lower-case letters:

```
q[0, 0, 1, 0] ---012--> q[0, 0, 1, 1]
q[0, 0, 1, 0] ---abc--> q[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Then, for either state we can continue to consume all of the input
we've encountered thus far, viz. that

```
q[0, 0, 1, 1] --ABC012--> q[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

and

```
q[0, 1, 1, 0] --ABCabc--> q[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Now, if we are in the state `q[0, 0, 1, 1]` and read a lower-case letter
we get to the state `q[0, 1, 1, 1]` and similarily if we are in the state
`q[0, 1, 1, 0]` and read a digit we end up in `q[0, 1, 1, 1]`. At this
point we've read 3 or more characters!

Now, from

```
q[0, 1, 1, 1]
```

we need to read two characters before we reach the accepting state.
Here I will use "X" to mean "Whatever, as long as its a character
from the set {0, 1, 2, a, b, c, A, B, C}".

So, from `q[0, 1, 1, 1]` we get the following sequence of transitions

```
q[0, 1, 1, 1] -- X --> Foo -- X --> q[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And when in `q[1, 1, 1, 1]` we have that

```
q[1, 1, 1, 1] -- X --> q[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

We can envision all of these transitions like so (I decided to omit
commas at this point to reduce the risk of line breaks on devices with
small screens),

```
                               ABCabc loops back here
                                         |
                                         V
                            +--abc--> q[0110] --012--+
                            |                        |
                            |                        V
 q[0000] --ABC--> q[0010] --+                     q[0111]-- X -- Foo -- X --> q[1111]
                  |     ^   |                        ^
                  |     |   |                        |
                  +-ABC-+   +--012--> q[0011] --abc--+
                                         ^
                                         |
                               ABC012 loops back here
```

Had we instead started with 012 we would have had

```
                               012abc loops back here
                                         |
                                         V
                            +--abc--> q[0101] --ABC--+
                            |                        |
                            |                        V
 q[0000] --012--> q[0001] --+                     q[0111]-- X -- Foo -- X --> q[1111]
                  |     ^   |                        ^
                  |     |   |                        |
                  +-012-+   +--ABC--> q[0011] --abc--+
                                         ^
                                         |
                               ABC012 loops back here
```

So there is a symmetry, and we could create a similar construct for
when the first construct is "abc". And that is the way the cookie
crumbles.